# bash: how to properly use sed for variables with spaces and quotation marks?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, escaping

I am very confused by this and it is messing with my code:
I am looking for a pattern containing spaces in a line, and I want to print the word after that pattern.
While I could escape the quotation marks in the line variable (using \"), I cannot do so in my actual data (the line is read directly from a file, whose format is given...)

I am seeing behaviour that I do not understand:

```
 lineone='#include "COMPLEX_Other_chain_X.itp"'
 linetwo='Other_chain_X       2'
 pattern='Other_chain_X      '
 #pattern='Other_chain_X\ \ \ \ \ \ ' #alternative pattern, same issues
```

issue 1: despite the pattern not being present in the line, sed prints sth (for $lineone)

```
 #this prints the entire value of $lineone, but should empty...
 echo "$lineone" |sed -e 's/.*Other_chain_X     //; s/}.*//' 
 #this works
 echo "$linetwo" |sed -e 's/.*Other_chain_X     //; s/}.*//' 


 #this give the output I want - because there are no spaces in the pattern I am looking for ?
 echo "$lineone" |sed -e 's/.*Other_chain_X//; s/}.*//' 
 echo "$linetwo" |sed -e 's/.*Other_chain_X//; s/}.*//'
```

issue 2: Again, sth is printed despite the pattern not matching (same case as for issue 1, but without using the variables lineone and linetwo.

```
 #why is the whole line printed here?
 echo '#include "COMPLEX_Other_chain_X.itp"' |sed -e 's/.*Other_chain_X     //; s/}.*//' 
 #my guess is that the syntax of the pattern with the spaces is wrong?

 echo "Other_chain_X       2" |sed -e 's/.*Other_chain_X     //; s/}.*//' #prints what I want

 echo "#include "COMPLEX_Other_chain_X.itp"" |sed -e "s/.*$pattern//; s/}.*//" #why is the whole line printed here?
 #my guess is that the syntax of the pattern with the spaces is not properly put into the variable?
 echo "Other_chain_X       2" |sed -e "s/.*$pattern//; s/}.*//" #prints what I want

 #why is the whole line printed here?
 echo "$lineone" |sed -e "s/.*$pattern//; s/}.*//" 
 echo "$linetwo" |sed -e "s/.*$pattern//; s/}.*//" #works fine
```

I realise that this is similar to other questions when people have to escape spaces or quotation marks - none of the explanations there have helped me though. The issue seems to be how the strings are saved in the variable.
Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

This is what works, but I do not understand why...

```
 echo "$linetwo" |sed -e "s/.*$pattern//; s/}.*//"
```

Problem in issue 1 and issue 2: sed prints despite pattern MISMATCH (lineone), no matter if variables or strings are used

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions. `$linetwo` gets split into two words which `echo` re-joins with a single space. Be sure to check your code with shellcheck.net before asking questions here.

Comment: Ah, I see. But what is wrong with: echo '#include "COMPLEX_Other_chain_X.itp"' |sed -e 's/.*Other_chain_X     //; s/}.*//'

Comment: The regular expression expects a space after `X`, which the input does not have.

Comment: exactly, so why is it priting sth?

Comment: Because `sed` still prints a line of input even if the substitution fails.

Comment: ok, can I turn this off? it is messing with my script...

Comment: the behavior is considered a feature/not a bug. Try the `sed -n ...` to turn off the default behavior. You will need to add a `p` (for print) at the end of each sub cmd like `sed -n -e 's/.*Other_chain_X     //p; s/}.*//p'` . Good luck.